# Как получить элемент в Set?

Tags: java

Как получить конкретный элемент например нужно получить только  "*Tim*" ?

```
  import java.util.HashSet;
  import java.util.Iterator;

   class IterateHashSet{ 
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     // Create a HashSet
      HashSet<String> hset = new HashSet<String>();

     //add elements to HashSet
     hset.add("Chaitanya");
     hset.add("Rahul");
     hset.add("Tim");
     hset.add("Rick");
     hset.add("Harry");

    Iterator<String> it = hset.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){

      System.out.println(it.next());//Chaitanya Rahul Tim Rick Harry  
   }

   }
 }
```

Comment: если в Set хранится строка "Tim", и ты хочешь получить строку "Tim" - какой смысл в Set? даже если бы была возможность сделать `set.get("Tim")`?

Comment: а если не я создаю set мне просто его нужно использовать,  достать значение  - так что поможет только конвертировать его в List или другую коллекцию  ?

Comment: @mtb, если я правильно понял вы хотите проверить наличие элемента в коллекции (если это так измените вопрос), для этого можно воспользоваться методом contains.

Comment: а если элементном в Set является объект а в нем нужно извлечь значение полей  ?

Comment: "а если элементном в Set является объект" ну тогда нужно указать объект в вопросе и по какому полю объекта вы будете находить нужный.

Answer (score 4):

```
hset.stream().filter(data -> Objects.equals(data, "Tim")).findFirst().get()
```

Comment: Тоже столкнулся с этим вопросом... Я так понял, что до появления Stream API можно было написать метод для поиска этого эемента, который использовал бы итератор...?

Comment: @Олексій Моренець, зачем? Куда проще -> делаем перебор элементов коллекции циклом -> в цикле выставляем условие на соответствие искомогу элемента -> return element;

Comment: @ GenCloud - Я вроде так и написал. Цикл по Set - это итератор, нет?

Answer (score 0):

```
cats.removeIf(elem -> elem.name.equals("Васька"));
```

Удаляет объект Cat с полем name == "Васька" из Set cats

Думаю, это примерно то что было нужно автору вопроса.
Я написал такое:

```
for (Cat elem : cats) {
    if (elem.name.equals("Васька")) cats.remove(elem);
}
```

а IDEA предложила сократить. Вообще полезно смотреть что она предлагает :)

Answer (score 0):

В **HashSet** - нельзя получить элемент по ключу.

**HashSet** инкапсулирует **HashMap**.
Вы лишь можете проверить наличие элемента в коллекции.

Если же все таки вам нужно получить элемент, тогда вы должны вызывать **iterator()** или используйте **for()** (под капотом он использует Iterator).
Если сразу вы решили, что вам нужно будет получать данные по ключу, то **HashSet** не подойдет вам как структура для хранения ваших элементов, во первых она не предназначена для этого, а во вторых сложность времени поиска элемента занимает O(n).